# How to use typescript and mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, express, mongoose

I have been working on an application for a few months and I have been starting to doubt my current backend architecture. I am building a backend with Typescript, mongoose and [routing-controllers](https://www.npmjs.com/package/routing-controllers).

I have a controller which handles the requests and passes them to a repository. I have two types of repositories. A normal repository (with which the controller interacts) and a model repository (which interacts with the mongoose model).

I also have defined some interfaces for the mongoose models. Let's say I have a user:

```
export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

export interface UserModel extends User, Document {
}
```

When the model is created it uses the UserModel.

Now my questions are:

1) Is this a correct  way of using nodejs?

2) When making a request with the model repository should the `User` interface or the `UserModel` interface be returned?

Currently I use it like this

```
public async getUserById(userId: string): Promise<UserModel> {
    return this.userModel.findById(userId);
}
```

And then the normal repository returns an object of the `User` interface.